# How to show billboard on setup progress window in basic msi project?

Tags: installation, installshield, installation-package

I have entered some values in BillBoard, BBControl, EventMapping tables through direct editor...
I can see billboard for InstallFiles action, but it is not being displayed for any other action...
I am also confused what value should i give in Feature column of billboard table....

Answer (score 1):

Billboards are associated with a specific action in [InstallExecuteSequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), usually InstallFiles.

Windows Installer doesn't support displaying a billboard across multiple actions. So using billboards is a good solution only for very large installers for which InstallFiles action takes a long time.

For smaller installers a better solution is using HTML host controls. This way you can create your own HTML with some slides. HTML host controls are supported only by some commercial setup authoring tools which offer an external UI.

Edit:

The main question is how long is your installation process and which action is the longest. You can determine this by creating an [install log](http://setupanddeployment.com/debugging/msi-log). If it's 1-2 minutes, it's not worth the effort. If it's 10-15 minutes, you can try this: http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/InstallShield2011/IHelpEUDialogsBillboard.htm

Comment: Thanks Cosmin for your reply...
But i want my setup look like Visual Studio's setup... like show list of actions which are in process...

Do you have any idea how i can do this...??

I am using basic msi project....

Comment: But i want some way to show user that which action is being processed as we can see list in visual studio's setup or in many other setups...

Like:
Copying Files
Creating Shortcuts
Writting Registry

all this in a list with checkmarks in front of them indicating which action is in process...

i hope you have any solution for this...!:)